# PHP setting variable inside function's function

Tags: php, oop, slim, slim-3

I need advice with setting variables. Im using Slim Framework. Ive got few classes.

**MailboxManager.php**

```
    public function getMailById($id) {
        /* @var $sql PDOStatement */
        $sql = $this->database->prepare("SELECT * FROM appmail_mails WHERE id = :id");
    $sql->bindParam('id', $id);
    $sql->execute();
    $record = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    if ($record === false) {
        return null;
    }
    $mail = new Mail($id);
    $mail->setMailContent($record['content']);
    $mail->setMailDate($record['date']);
    $mail->setMailSubject($record['subject']);
    $mail->setMailSize($record['
return $mail;
```

**MailController.php**

```
class MailController
private $id;
public function showMail()
    $mail = ServicesFactory::getMailboxManager()->getMailById($this->id);
    echo "<pre>";
    var_dump($mail);
```

Now I want to create path with Slim Framework. In index php I put:

```
$app->get('/dupa/{id}', function(ServerRequestInterface $request){

    $id = $request->getAttribute('id');
    echo $id;
    $new = new MailController();
    $test = $new->showMail();
    var_dump($test);
});
```

How am I supposed to set id for:

```
$mail = ServicesFactory::getMailboxManager()->getMailById($this->id);
```

to properly get it?
Everytime I'm trying to:

```
$test = $new->showMail($id)
```

I just get null.

Thanks for you help.

Comment: your `showMail()` does return anything ??

Comment: Yes, it returns null

Comment: Your function `showMail()` is not expecting any id. How do you expect the MailController to get the id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The route params are passed as the third argument to your closure

```
$app->get('/dupa/{id}', function(ServerRequestInterface $request, $response, $args){

    $id = $args['id'];
    echo $id;
    $new = new MailController();
    $test = $new->showMail();
    var_dump($test);
});
```